# Not getting autocomplete suggestions in single xml file formatted as per Android xml-merging aapt tool style

Tags: android

Tried to create animated vector drawables for my app by following from [AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable) documentation. As mentioned on there, when those drawable, vector-drawable and animator files are kept separate as mentioned in section [Define an AnimatedVectorDrawable in three separate XML files](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable#define-an-animatedvectordrawable-in-three-separate-xml-files), on pressing `Ctrl+Space` in those individual files, the auto-complete suggestions appear, which is easy to build the xml code, but when those individual xml codes are kept together in a single xml file following aapt tool format as mentioned in section [Define an AnimatedVectorDrawable all in one XML file](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable#define-an-animatedvectordrawable-all-in-one-xml-file), the auto-complete suggestions don't appear in that single xml file. This is the issue with aapt tool specific xml formatting only.

Is there any way to resolve this issue and get auto-complete suggestions on pressing `Ctrl+Space` in the single xml file?